# How to use scrapy to crawl a website which hides the url as href="javascript:;" in the next button

Tags: javascript, python, pagination, web-crawler, scrapy

I am learning python and scrapy lately. I googled and searched around for a few days, but I don't seem to find any instruction on how to crawl multiple pages on a website with hidden urls - `<a href="javascript:;"`. Basically each page contains 20 listings, each time you click on ">>" button, it will load the next 20 items. I can't figure out how to find the actual urls, below is the source code for your reference. Any pointers and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what I gather, the button is implemented with an anchor element? Without knowing what the website is, it would be difficult to help. My guess is that the anchor onClick event is getting bound to some javascript function that fires an AJAX call when the anchor is clicked. Depending on the site (and how obfuscated it is) tracing the location of the actual HTTP request could be challenging.

Comment: you can see the site at rent.591.com.hk, it's in chinese, but you can switch it to Eng on top right corner. Any further help is much appreciated junnytony

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser developer tools to see which requests that site is doing.

Comment: I tried, on the top of Network tab shows "http://rent.591.com.hk/?m=home&c=search&a=rsllist&type=1&p=2&searchtype=1". I copied this URL and pasted it on a browser, empty page displayed. Under Network Tab -> Initiator, it shows query-1.8.2.min.js:2, not sure if it tells me anything. Btw, I went on to try Selenium to mimic clicking on the >> button for next page, when i checked the URL (driver.current_url) after the click action, it always displays http://rent.591.com.hk/#list, the URL is still hidden. I appreciate a lot  if someone can give me a hand to resolve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visiting the site with a Web-Browser and activated Web-Developer-Tools (the following screenshots are made with Firefox and add-on Firebug) you should be able to analyze the Network requests and responses. It will show you that the sites pagination buttons send requests like the following:

[image]

So the URL seems to be:

> http://rent.591.com.hk/?m=home&c=search&a=rslist&type=1&shType=list&p=2&searchtype=1

But it's not a normal request. It's a `XMLHttpRequest`. Indicated unter the `Header` tab. And the response is in JSON:

[image]

So you don't need to grab the data from complicated nested html-structures, but can get the directly from the JSON dict.

I ended up with this scrapy code (with room for improvement):

```
import scrapy
import json

class RentObject(scrapy.Item):
    address = scrapy.Field()
    purpose = scrapy.Field()
    # Add more fields as needed

class ScrapeSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "rent_hk"
    allowed_domains = ['591.com.hk']
    start_urls = ['http://rent.591.com.hk/?hl=en-us#list' ]

    page_number = 0
    page_num_max = 5 # for test purposes grab only up to 5 pages

    def parse(self, response):

        if 'page_number' in response.meta:
            result_dict = json.loads(response.body)  # get data as dict
            for object in result_dict['items']:
                ro = RentObject()
                ro['address'] = object['address']
                ro['purpose'] = object['purpose']
                yield ro

        # Make request for (next page) JSON data
        self.page_number += 1

        payload = {
            'm': 'home',
            'c': 'search',
            'a': 'rslist',
            'type': '1',
            'p': str(self.page_number),
            'searchtype': '1'
        }

        if self.page_number < self.page_num_max:
            request = scrapy.FormRequest(url='http://rent.591.com.hk/',
                                         method='GET',
                                         formdata=payload,
                                         headers={'Referer': 'http://rent.591.com.hk/?hl=en-us',
                                                  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
                                         callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['page_number'] = self.page_number
            yield request
```

The site is really not easy for a scrapy beginner - so I compiled this detailed answer.

Comment: Firebug is not the only option. There's also a builtin tool in Firefox and one in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks @ArturGaspar for the hint. I reworded my answer to be less Firefox/Firebug centric.

Comment: Frank, I really appreciate your help and taking time out to try this out. I ended up using Selenium to mimic the browser clicking action on >> button and collected all the subsequent pages links I needed, though I still did this under Scrapy framework as I will use it to filter out the elements and build the Item list. I will certainly try yours to learn the Scrapy-alone way, plus the info about Firebug is useful for my future development. Again your help is much appreciated. I am new to stackoverflow, pls let me know how I can rate your answer.